# How in c++ are handled the template classes' static attribute in different OSs?

Tags: templates, c++11, static, linker

A quite technical question because I've a problem on windows with a static attribute of template class...

Say for exemple :

A.h

```
template <class T>
class A
{
private:
static T * obj;

public:
   template <typename... Args>
   static inline void ini(Args... args)
   {
      if (!obj) obj = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   }

   static inline T * get()
   {
      assert(obj);
      return obj;
   }

   // [...] other methods.
}
template <class T>
T*  A<T>::obj = nullptr;
// Yeah, A = something like a c++11 style singleton class
```

B.h

```
class B: A<B>
{
    //[...]
}
```

main.cpp (executed first)

```
B::ini();
```

C0.cpp

```
B * b = B::get();
```

C1.cpp

```
B * b = B::get();
```

Ok, quite simple up to now, but say we compile modulary : does the linker automatically consider that B::obj is exactely the same  in main.o, C1.o and C0.o ? (*.o is the object file, not necessarily from gcc)
if not, how to make it so ?

Then, consider that we first compile C1.cpp and C0.cpp in an extern dll (libC.so or libC.a/libC.lib + C.dll depending the compiler/OS) and then main, which is the executable, linked to C.dll/so. What about B::obj ? it should exist in both the lib and the exe...
How to make it designating the same thing ? Or if this is the case, how the system does handle it ?
We can suppose also there are many libs using this symbol (as static or dynamic pluggin).

Actually, I'm asking these questions because on linux, when I compiled a such app, the symbols was correctly resolved and there was only one B::obj instance.
But now I'm compiling the same with mingw and the get after the init from a different lib doesn't pass the assert, I concluded there is one instance per lib...

Comment: sorry, I've forgotten 2 lines ^^
in A.h as this

Answer (score 0):

It is not just templates. Any time you have a static variable that is used in a DLL, it uses a copy of that static variable within the DLL. When you use the "same" variable in the EXE, you use a copy within the EXE. Changes to the copy in the DLL will not be reflected in the copy used by the EXE, and vice versa.

With some difficulty (or with an appropriate third-party library) you can create a Singleton pattern so that both the DLL and the EXE use the same instance of the Singleton. You can then put variables that would have been static in the Singleton. Your template class `A` can use a Singleton class to store `obj`, and you can use other Singleton classes elsewhere if needed.

Alternatively, perhaps you can redesign your template so that `obj` is not static.

Comment: Actually, A IS the singleton class in my app...
the question is about how to create such a singleton class where user doesn't need to define A<T>::obj

but sorry, There was another copy-past fail, and the declaration of obj was not present

Comment: As you're discovering, it's hard to "roll your own" singleton classes in Windows when you link DLLs. I wouldn't even try it in my own software. Instead, I've had success using the Singleton pattern provided by ACE (http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html). I believe there are other third-party packages that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching around for the same problem too. Here is my current solution, using c++11 explicit instantiation declaration:

```
// B.h
class B;
// explicit instantiation declaration 
extern template class A<B>;
class B: public A<B> {
    //...
};
```

And add a B.cpp

```
// B.cpp
// explicit instantiation definition 
template class A<B>;
```

Now for main.cpp, C0.cpp and C1.cpp (they all include B.h) there will be no code generated for A and use the unique one generated in B.cpp

PS: I'm not sure whether it is the correct way to use the 'extern template' coz it seems that it is used primarily to reduce compilation time.